# How to check if a linux screen is running & attached?

Tags: php, linux

Ok so i have a website (i host with shared hosting), and i have an auth server, the auth server will only function if a screen is running and attached. So i need to know whether or not atleast one screen is running so at login i can check if auth server is running.

e.g.
on my webite in php this is just an example to possibly help you undersand my question better.

Ok so say my VPS ip is 1.2.3.4, in php would it be possible to check if a screen is running and attached on a linux server using the IP?
so like

```
if(checkIfAnyScreensRunningAndAttachedOnLinuxVPS("1.2.3.4"))
{
    //good. A there is an active and attached screen on my linux VPS
}
```

Comment: Do you mean a physical "screen" or the "screen" command-line utility?

Comment: Are the website and the auth server the same box? You can use PHP to do something like check for running `X` processes locally but there isn't any general purpose way to check if a remote machine has a running X server.